# Encode equal sign in query string with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a query string that may look like one of the following:

1. ?key=aa=bb
2. ?key=aa=bb=cc
3. ?key=aa=bb&key2=cc

etc.

What I want to do is replace the equal sign in the value part only. So it should result in this:

1. ?key=aa%3dbb
2. ?key=aa%3dbb%3dcc
3. ?key=aa%3dbb&key2=cc

I'm trying to do that with the following regex by using a look ahead. But it's not doing anything.

```
echo preg_replace("/=(?=[^&])=/", "%3d", 'http://www.example.com?key=aaa=bbb=ccc&key3=dddd');
```

[Example code here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qEBjtJ)

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why not simply use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\bkey\d*)=(*SKIP)(*F)|=
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/13

```
$re = "/(\\bkey\\d*)=(*SKIP)(*F)|=/m"; 
$str = "\n    ?key=aa=bb\n    ?key=aa=bb=cc\n    ?key=aa=bb&key2=cc\n"; 
$subst = "%3d"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex, use the proper tools.  `parse_url()` to get the query string (and whatever else you want), then `parse_str()` to get an array of the var/vals. Then `http_build_query()` will encode for you:

```
$query = parse_url('http://www.example.com?key=aaa=bbb=ccc&key3=dddd', PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $array);
$result = http_build_query($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of a regex based on the same approach as vks':

```
[&?][^&=]+=(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|=
```

**Regex explanation**:

- `[&?]` - Match `&` or `?` literally
- `[^&=]+` - Match characters other than `&` and `=`
- `=` - Match `=` (so, we matched a `key`)
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - Verbs that fail the match at this point (we do not replace this `=` we found after `key`)
- `=` - We match any other `=` and we'll remove it.

Here is [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/OzEu62):

```
$re = "/[&?][^&=]+=(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|=/"; 
$str = "http://google.com?key=aa=bb\nhttp://google.com?key=aa=bb=cc\nhttp://google.com?key=aa=bb&key2=cc"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "%3d", $str);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
preg_replace_callback("/=([^&$]+)/", "myReplace", "http://www.example.com?key=aaa=bbb=ccc&key3=dddd");

function myReplace($matches) {
  return "=" . urlencode($matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna add an addendum, explaining your specific attempt:

```
preg_replace("/=(?=[^&])=/",
                 ↑      ↑
```

While the lookahead was a nice idea, it really just would match a single character. And in this case just would have asserted the very next character not to be `&`.

You could refashion it into:

```
preg_replace("/=([^&=]+)\K=/",
                         ↑
```

Which I guess is what you tried. Note that this merely ignores every second `=………=` equal sign. So would only suit your simple example query strings, not more plentiful unescaped characters within.